# How to patch/put data in nodejs and mongodb API using react hook

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, react-hooks

I have an API which I'm using react to consume. The data displays list of products and the prices in tabular form. I've tested all API endpoints with Postman, all routes are working fine. Now, I'm building a react frontend to consume the API. I'm having issues updating a product. Below is my code.

My Home.js

```
const Home = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const history = useHistory()

  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const [currentName, setCurrentName] = useState("");
  const [currentPrice, setCurrentPrice] = useState("");

  const editRow = (id, name, price) => {
    setCurrentName(name);
    setCurrentPrice(price);
    console.log(name +": "+ price);
    history.push(`/edit/${id}`)
  }

  const deleteProduct = (id) => {
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      fetch(`products/${id}`, { method: 'DELETE' })
        .then(async response => {
          const data = await response.json();
          if (!response.ok) {
            const error = (data && data.message) || response.ok;
            return Promise.reject(error);
          }
          console.log('Deleted succesfully!');
          window.location.reload();
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('There was an error: ', error);
        })
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/products")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result.products);
        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
  }, []);

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <Container className={classes.root}>
        <ProductsList items={items} editRow={editRow} deleteProduct={deleteProduct} />

        <div>
          <Button 
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            href="/addproducts">
              <AddBoxIcon/> Add Products
          </Button>
        </div>
      </Container>
    )
  }  
}

export default Home;
```

My ProductList.js

```
function ProductsList(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const capitalise = (word) => {
    let res = word.toUpperCase();
    return res
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="customized table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <StyledTableCell><h2>Item</h2></StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right"><h2>Price</h2></StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right"><h2>Edit</h2></StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right"><h2>Delete</h2></StyledTableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {props.items.length > 0 ? (
              props.items.map((item, id) => (
                <StyledTableRow key={id}>
                  <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">
                    {capitalise(item.name)}
                  </StyledTableCell>
                  <StyledTableCell align="right">{item.price}</StyledTableCell>
                  <StyledTableCell align="right">
                    <EditIcon
                      onClick={() => props.editRow(item._id, item.name,item.price)}
                      >
                    </EditIcon>
                  </StyledTableCell>
                  <StyledTableCell align="right">
                    <DeleteForeverIcon
                      onClick={() => props.deleteProduct(item._id)}
                      >
                    </DeleteForeverIcon>
                  </StyledTableCell>
                </StyledTableRow>
              ))
            ) : (
              <StyledTableCell align="right">No item</StyledTableCell>
            )}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>      
    </>    
  );    
  }

export default ProductsList;
```

My EditUserForm.js

```
const EditUserForm = (props) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const match = useRouteMatch();
  let routeId = match.params.id;
  console.log(routeId);

  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [item, setItem] = useState([]);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setItem({ ...item, [name]: value});
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    updateProduct();
    history.push('/');
  }
 
  const updateProduct = (routeId) => {
    fetch(`/addproducts/${routeId}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: item.name,
        price: item.price 
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => setItem(result))
      .catch((err) => console.log('error: ', err))      
  }

  return (
        
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
      <label>Name</label>
      <input 
        type="text"
        name="name"
        value=""
        onChange={handleInputChange} 
      />

      <label>Price</label>
      <input 
        type="text" 
        name="price" 
        value=""
        onChange={handleInputChange}
      />

      <button>Update</button>
      <button
        onClick={() => props.setEditing(false)}
        >
        Cancel
      </button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default EditUserForm
```

The POST and DELETE are working fine.